# Test for empty RichText field

Tags: conditional, redactor, richtext

I have a rich text field which contains:

```
<p><br></p>
```

This is what is left when you delete all content of a redactor field.
This can't be deleted without the HTML view of Redactor.

Is it possible to write a conditional that checks for an empty field ignoring HTML markup?

```
{% if entry.poorText is not empty %}
   {{ entry.poorText }}
{% endif %}
```

Does not work in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`striptags`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html) filter to remove all HTML tags from your string. With the [`trim`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html) filter you can strip all whitespace from the beginning and the end of it:

```
{% if entry.poorText|striptags|trim %}
    {{ entry.poorText }}
{% else %}
    Here could be a nicely formatted text! 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: in twig, an empty string evaluates to `false`, so you could just test `{% if entry.poorText|striptags|trim %}`

Comment: Right. Thx @Marion.